# Making a sequence of tuples unique by a specific element

Tags: python, set, tuples

So I have a tuple of tuples

```
a = ((1, 2), (7, 2), (5, 2), (3, 4), (8, 4))
```

I would like to remove all the tuples from 'a' which have the a common second element, except for one (any one of them).

For the example above I would like the new output `a = ((1,2),(3,4))`

In other words I would like to eliminate tuples which are considered duplicate elements in the second position of the tuple.

I would like to know the most efficient way to achieve this, and also like to know if I can do the same with lists instead of tuples?

Comment: Ive just used set(a) here to eliminate duplicates like ((1,2),(1,2))

Comment: @BobStack: right, so you have a sequence of *tuples* and want to eliminate duplicates based on a single element in the tuple.

Comment: Yes, @MartijnPieters

Comment: Sets are also inherently unordered, so you're better off using tuples rather than sets for the inner "sets."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a *dictionary* from your elements, with whatever you wanted to be unique as the key, then extracting the values. This works for anything where the 'unique' sub-element is hashable. Integers are hashable:

```
def unique_by_key(elements, key=None):
    if key is None:
        # no key: the whole element must be unique
        key = lambda e: e
    return {key(el): el for el in elements}.values()
```

This function is pretty generic; it can be used to extract 'unique' elements by any trait, as long as whatever the `key` callable returns can be used as a key in a dictionary. Order will not be preserved, and currently the last element per key wins.

With the above function you can use a [`operator.itemgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) or a lambda to extract your second value from each element. This then works for both a sequence of tuples and a sequence of lists:

```
from operator import itemgetter

unique_by_second_element = unique_by_key(a, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a = ((1, 2), (7, 2), (5, 2), (3, 4), (8, 4))
>>> unique_by_key(a, key=itemgetter(1))
[(5, 2), (8, 4)]
>>> b = [[1, 2], [7, 2], [5, 2], [3, 4], [8, 4]]
>>> unique_by_key(b, key=itemgetter(1))
[[5, 2], [8, 4]]
```

Note that the function always returns a *list*; you can always convert that back by calling `tuple()` on the result.

Comment: The use of itemgetter is actually to treat the second element in each tuple as a key for the dictionary?

Comment: @omri_saadon: exactly. The `key` callable is used to extract whatever it is you want to make your elements unique by. In this case `itemgetter(1)` returns the element at index 1 for each element and uses that as a key in the dictionary. That means only *one copy* of each element with the same value at index 1 is kept.